# Not able to show tables from hive metastore using presto

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, presto

I am trying to configuring presto 0.60 with Hadoop 2 and Hive remote Metastore. When I try to access the tables "presto cli" through the following error.

```
./presto.jar --server name:9083 --catalog default --debug
```

Error:

```
2014-03-18T18:50:23.739+0100     WARN   completer-0 com.google.common.cache.LocalCace
Exception thrown during refresh
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timeout
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[presto.jar:0.60]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[presto.jar:0.60]

at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) [presto.jar:0.60]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135) ~[presto.jar:0.60]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2346) [presto.at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment$1.run(LocalCache.java:2329) ~[presto.jar:0.60]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [presto.jar:0.60]
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156) [presto.jar:0.60]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead :

```
./presto.jar --server <presto_coordinator>:8080 --catalog default --debug
```